# JQuery find and change class of all elements with data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have tried various ways of finding all elements with a specific data attribute to change their class.  Currently I have this, which is not working for the other elements on the same parent div, `#search_list_container`:

```
$( '#search_list_container' ).on( 'click', '.favourite', function () {
            $(this).removeClass('favourite');
            $(this).addClass('favourite_selected');
            var fav = $(this).attr( 'data-specimen');
            $("[data-favourite='"+ fav +"']").removeClass('favourite');
            $("[data-favourite='"+ fav +"']").addClass('favourite_selected');
```

Specifically the lines

```
$("[data-favourite='"+ fav +"']").removeClass('favourite');
$("[data-favourite='"+ fav +"']").addClass('favourite_selected');
```

The clicked element changes class OK, but I want the other elements on the the same div (`#search_list_container`) to also change class.

The HTML is:

```
    <div id='search_list_container'>
                <div id='search_list_container_left'></div>
<div class="favourite" data-specimen="586" title="Toggle as Favourite"></div>
                <div id='search_list_container_right'></div>
<div class="favourite" data-specimen="586" title="Toggle as Favourite"></div>
            </div>
```

The elements on the left aren't changing, but the elements on the right are.  They have the same data attribute.

CSS:

```
.favourite{
    background: url(../images/favourite_plain.png) no-repeat center;
    width:20px;
    height:17px;
    margin-left:20px;
    cursor:pointer;
    float:left;
}

.favourite_selected{
    background: url(../images/favourite_selected.png) no-repeat center;
    width:20px;
    height:17px;
    margin-left:20px;
    cursor:pointer;
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the minimal HTML to reproduce? It's always better to create a simple snippet of your problem :-)

Comment: Show html with your divs

Comment: I don't see any `data-favourite` attribute in your minimal HTML neither do I see any classes. Please see [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: where is class `.favourite` in html ?

Comment: HTML is missing basic information such as elements with class favourite and attribute data-specimen

Comment: we need the html. the pic is not gonna help.

Comment: I might just be me but I don't want to register on a random site... if you want to get help just post a JSFiddle or use the builtin code snippets. (and you spelled 'you' instead of 'view' :D)

Comment: OK, sorry, but it's a database driven site and quite complex, I have updated the minimal HTML in the OP

Comment: You could copy the `HTML` from the loaded site.. also I think we're missing CSS(?) for this to work

Comment: The css change is working on the elements on the right but not the identical ones on the left with the same data attribute..

Comment: Okay, so... I need your CSS to view the results. I think you are expecting people to fix your code by just looking at it. Some really good developers might be able to do that but I'm certainly not. I need a working code to view the result and test different things :)

Comment: CSS added if that helps.  Not really asking people to 'fix' my code, just a clarification as to why it's not working as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 issues with your code.

1: you are selecting a single element using $(this) and then adding  and removing class. This is why only on the clicked element classes are getting updated.

2: You are using the wrong attribute data-favourite to select elements, you need to use data-specimen.

```js
$('#search_list_container' ).on( 'click', '.favourite', function () {
            var fav = $(this).attr( 'data-specimen');
            $("[data-specimen='"+ fav +"']").removeClass('favourite');
            $("[data-specimen='"+ fav +"']").addClass('favourite_selected');
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <div id='search_list_container'>
                <div id='search_list_container_left'></div>
<div class="favourite" data-specimen="586" title="Toggle as Favourite">First</div>
                <div id='search_list_container_right'></div>
<div class="favourite" data-specimen="586" title="Toggle as Favourite">Second</div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a `data-favourite` attribute in your HTML, if you want to change the class of all `data-specimen` you should rather use `$("[data-specimen='"+ fav +"']")` like so :

```js
$('#search_list_container').on('click', '.favourite', function() {
  $(this).removeClass('favourite');
  $(this).addClass('favourite_selected');
  var fav = $(this).attr('data-specimen');
  $("[data-specimen='" + fav + "']").removeClass('favourite');
  $("[data-specimen='" + fav + "']").addClass('favourite_selected');
})
```

```css
.favourite {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.favourite_selected {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>
<div id='search_list_container'>
  <div id='search_list_container_left'>Test1</div>
  <div class="favourite" data-specimen="586" title="Toggle as Favourite">Test2</div>
  <div id='search_list_container_right'>Test3</div>
  <div class="favourite" data-specimen="586" title="Toggle as Favourite">Test4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, must have glazed over that obvious error.  Your answer was of course also correct.